# Is it possible to turn off drag and drop in vscode?

Tags: drag-and-drop, visual-studio-code

This is killing me. I have a problem with accidentally dragging files in to other locations. I seem to fall victim to this a lot more often in vscode than in other editors. Is there any plugin, setting, or something that will save me from my incompetent mouse skills?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem. Its very annoying when a folder goes awol by accident. To resolve it just add the following setting to your user settings in file -> preferences -> settings.

```html
{
  "explorer.enableDragAndDrop": false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I echo this issue. Drag and drop is handy when intentional so in settings just set:

```
"explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": true
```

Comment: Hi Jason, welcome to stack overflow! Could you edit your question to add an explanation  of the result of this action? Currently, it's not clear what the effect will be. I also recommend you remove 'I echo this issue' - SO is like an encyclopaedia where it's best to avoid information that isn't directly relevant to the question/answer.